# Symfony and ajax list with pagination and filters (based on js framework)

Tags: angularjs, symfony, backbone.js, knockout.js

I would like to ask you If someone has any experiences with symfony and some ajax list supporting pagination and filters. The ideal solution would be solution based on angular or similar javascript frameworks (backbone, knockout...).

I see a lot of examples which handle this functionality but none of them supports pagination which would load only given limit and offset from the backend.

Thanky for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should check http://datatables.net/ There is also a bundle to use for Symfony entities https://github.com/AliHichem/AliDatatableBundle